# Reset a destination date column value

Tags: zapier

I can already change the value of a destination **DateTime** field by assigning it e.g. `2000-01-01 00:00`. But if either of the systems changes their timezone, this value will also change with them, so I cannot rely on it always keeping this value.

So, is there a way to clear the value of the column?

If we do not type or insert a value, Zapier assumes that we do not want to update it.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to put 3 spaces in the field? It works for Airtable, maybe it will work here too.

Comment: being able to clear a column depends on what the destination app is and how they've implemented those updates. It will vary app-to-app on Zapier